# Disable section of HTML code when Javascript Disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a website for a university project where I'm using a piece of Javascript ( http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ ) in order to generate a background that is a gallery of several images.

I'm trying to set the site so that it will display a single image as the background in the event of Javascript being turned off, but the navigation elements of this slideshow are generated using HTML code outside of the script tags and inside the body tag.

Is there a way I can set this HTML code so that it will only be included when Javascript is active, leaving the screen clear of the navigation controls when it isn't?

At request the code I'm trying to isolate is the Div tags being called below.

```
<!--Thumbnail Navigation-->
<div id="prevthumb"></div>
<div id="nextthumb"></div>

<!--Arrow Navigation-->
<!-- <a id="prevslide" class="load-item"></a>
<a id="nextslide" class="load-item"></a>

<div id="thumb-tray" class="load-item">
    <div id="thumb-back"></div>
    <div id="thumb-forward"></div>
</div>

<!--Time Bar-->
<!--<div id="progress-back" class="load-item">
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
</div>

<!--Control Bar-->
<div id="controls-wrapper" class="load-item">
    <div id="controls">

        <a id="play-button"><img id="pauseplay" src="img/pause.png"/></a>

        <!--Slide counter-->
        <div id="slidecounter">
            <span class="slidenumber"></span> / <span class="totalslides"></span>
        </div>

        <!--Slide captions displayed here-->
        <div id="slidecaption"></div>

        <!--Thumb Tray button-->
        <a id="tray-button"><img id="tray-arrow" src="img/button-tray-up.png"/></a>

        <!--Navigation-->
        <ul id="slide-list"></ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include the code you're having trouble with in the question? Right now if that site changes, this question becomes useless.

Comment: Will do, though really the code itself is just calling some Divs in the body section. @GeorgeStocker

Comment: Hide #controls-wrapper by default. If Javascript is enabled, then display it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I really don't see why you've closed this question? It was immediately obvious what OP was asking.

Comment: @jumpingcode, the post was edited after it was closed. The original question was not self-contained enough to be reasonably answerable if the link were to succumb to link rot.

Comment: @jumpingcode That's worked, thanks a lot :-). It hadn't occurred to me to do it like that.

Comment: Who is disabling javascript? As we are in the era of AJAX.

Comment: @jumpingcode zzzzBov's comment is correct. Initially this question just had a link to a third party page and effectively said, "I have an issue, how do I do that thing they do on that page?"  Those types of questions are closed for a few reasons: 1) If that site changes, this question becomes useless for all future visitors 2) If that link dies, this question becomes useless for all future visitors. 3) questions should be self-contained. As a user coming in from Google and seeing this question, I shouldn't need to go to another site to see if our code was similar.

Comment: Ah apologies, I just saw the still fairly new question with all it's edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jumpingcode mentioned, you would want to hide the controls in question with CSS, and show them with JavaScript.

Hide the div with CSS:

```
#controls-wrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

Then show it in your page with jQuery:

```
$('#controls-wrapper').show();
```

Or use `.css()` to have more control over what type of `display` property to use:

```
$('#controls-wrapper').css('display', 'block');
```